Why did Nigel Farage choose Clacton as the constituency to campaign in?
Nigel Farage has now been elected as a Reform UK MP for Clacton. Did he explain why he chose to campaign in Clacton specifically, rather than any other constituency?

I've been to Clacton and even before the election, there was a great deal of sympathy for the kind of anti-immigration policies being pushed by Reform.

@Valorum - I believe the constituency includes Jaywick, which has achieved a certain notoriety as a kind of 'chav hell'.

Farage was brought up in Kent, and I'm pretty sure he'd been living in Clacton long before his very recent decision to come "out of retirement", take over leadreship of Reform, and stand for election again. So I think this question is a bit weaselly.

@FumbleFingers "Because he lives there" would be a pretty convincing answer if you're willing to post it as one.

@F1Krazy: I was kinda hoping someone could research it better than me. Googling "when did nigel farage move to clacton"  gets nothing relevant for me! But I'm fairly sure whenever he did move there, he wasn't expecting to stand for Clacton in this election.

@FumbleFingers "Googling "when did nigel farage move to clacton" gets nothing relevant for me" - That might be because, from what I can find, he doesn't actually live in Clacton after all - he lives in the village of Downe in Greater London, a 90-minute drive away.

@F1Krazy: Well, I can't remember where I got the idea he lived in Clacton (I sometimes watch GB News, where both the name and the man himself appear regularly). But given the number of nutters who I'm sure Farage has police protection against, and the fact that the Express piece says where Farage reportedly has a family home, I don't necessarily assume I was mistaken. And I do believe Farage's own assertion that until very recently, he was not planning / expecting to take up arms against yet another sea of troubles!

Reform UK seems to have a knack for appealing to depressed seaside towns. 4 out of the 5 constituencies they won (Clacton, Great Yarmouth, Boston and Skegness, South Basildon and East Thurrock) are coastal with at least one depressed seaside town.

Clacton was seen as the seat most likely to elect a Reform MP, so it makes sense that Farage as party leader chose to stand there. (Farage became leader at the same time he announced he would stand.) A Survation poll from January showed that about 18% of voters in Clacton supported the Reform candidate there, rising to 37% (and winning by 10 points) if Farage would be the candidate instead. That's compared to national polls at the time which had Reform at between 4% and 13% support.
Survation (or rather, their client Arron Banks) most likely chose Clacton as the place to conduct the survey because it's where the UK Independence Party's first MP, Douglas Carswell, was elected in 2014. At that time, Farage was leader of UKIP, so it's likely there would be a lot of overlap between those who supported UKIP under his leadership, and those who would support him in 2024.
That he stood for a different party probably would not hurt his chances; in the media, Farage was almost synonymous with UKIP anyway, and UKIP's platform then was quite similar to Reform's platform now (with the obvious exception that Reform are not now campaigning for Brexit, which has already happened).
